# C++ vector push_back async object in for loop

Tags: c++, asynchronous, std, stdvector

I was coding a for loop in C++11, where I needed to push back an async object onto a vector. I wanted to split the object initialization into two steps:

```cpp
    std::vector<std::future<bool>> asyncThreads;

    for (int i = 0; i < processorCount; i++) {
        auto boundFunc = std::bind(&Foo::foo, this);
        auto asyncThread = std::async(std::launch::async, boundFunc)

        asyncThreads.push_back(asyncThread);
    }
```

Now I do realize that both `boundFunc` and `asyncThread` objects go out of scope at the end of the for loop (the `push_back` function should copy/move the values though), but then why does directly declaring the objects in the `push_back call` work? Like so:

```cpp
    std::vector<std::future<bool>> asyncThreads;

    for (int i = 0; i < processorCount; i++) {
        asyncThreads.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, std::bind(&Foo::foo, this)));
    }
```

Comment: The difference is `std::async(...)` is an rvalue expression while `asyncThread` is an lvalue expression. The first example tries to copy the `future` while the second moves it. Try using `std::move`.

Comment: What's the difference between rvalue and lvalue? And how would I use the move function here? Sorry, still a bit new to c++

Comment: You can take a look at [What is move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics).

Comment: @user2793618 lvalue is simply almost everything that has a name (`int a = 5`), rvalue is value or expression that can occur only on the right side of `=` (literal strings, numbers etc)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for the link, was informative. But why is it that copying the ```future``` object causes the code to fail, while moving it is ok?

Comment: @user2793618 A `std::future` is not copyable, but it is moveable. A future represents a resource that cannot be meaningfully shared, so its copy semantics are explicitly prevented to avoid errors. You can see [it's constructors here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/future). The copy constructor (3) is `= delete` (disabled) while the move constructor (2) is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::future` object is not copyable, but moveable. So therefore, you must call move on the object to push it onto the vector.